# i18n rails 4 production error. not development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

I'm developing a rails 4 application with i18n support. I've installed i18n gem. In my application.rb file I have this code

```
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
config.i18n.available_locales = [:es]
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
```

In development mode all works flawlessly, but when I switch to production everything outputs "translation missing". I tried different solutions such as write this code in config/initializers/locale.rb

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}')]
I18n.default_locale = :es
```

And also write this in config/environment.rb

```
I18n.reload!
```

Nothing worked. Going to console mode shows this, the same as when I open the app in web browser.

```
user@opendraft:/home/user/www/awesomeapp# RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.1)
irb(main):001:0> I18n.t('btn_login')
=> "Acceder"
irb(main):002:0> exit
user@opendraft:/home/user/www/awesomeapp# RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c
Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.1)
irb(main):001:0> I18n.t('btn_login')
=> "translation missing: es.btn_login"
irb(main):002:0> exit
```

My config/locales/es.yml file:

```
es:
  btn_login: "Acceder"
  reset: "Reinicializar"
  login: "Acceso"
  sign_up_candidate: "Candidatos"
  sign_up_company: "Empresas"
  sign_up_teacher: "Profesores"
```

Comment: Show us your config/locales/es.yml and its btn_login key.

Comment: Posted, thanks for watching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All translations from `config/locales/*` are auto loaded, according to comments included on `application.rb`.

I have some apps using only `:es` as locale, and the only configuration in `application.rb` is:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
```

Nothing else.

**Edit**

Checking my app, I can see that

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:es]
```

is necessary if you want to remove any reference to `:en` locale. You can check it with this:

```
I18n.locale_available?(:en) # => false
```

---

FYI, In a Rails 3 app using only `:es` as locale, I have this line too:

```
I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = false
```

Simply to avoid the deprecation warning:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future.
If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I cleaned all files, removed i18n gem from Gemfile to allow rails install default i18n gem and now it's working. Too much junk gives problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove config/initializers/locale.rb from your application. Default config looking like that:

```
# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
# config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

so rails already loading everything in config/locales/*.rb,yml. And I can assure you, that code you provide works out of box with default configuration.